# Is there a setting in Firefox that will prohibit a page from resizing of my window?

Tags: firefox

I really get annoyed when a page re-sizes my window. Is there a setting in Firefox that will prohibit the windows from resizing?

Comment: Do you have an example?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I think this will do what you want: Go to

```
Tools>Options>Content tab>Enable Javascript>Advanced
```

Uncheck “Move or resize existing windows”

[image]

Comment: Apparently we were typing our answers at the same time,  Sorry for the duplicate.

Comment: @Kevin No problem. Yes, almost simultaneously. I was only 8 seconds faster. I have done that many times so far.

Answer (score 6):

Goto the  "Content' tab in Preferences.  Click the 'Advanced" button next to enable javascript and uncheck the appropriate box